# High resolution video file not playing in exoplayer

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I need some help, I am developing video player with the help of Exo player and this is working fine but when I am trying to play big resolution file like 4k or 2k so I am getting this error- mediacodec video renderer error index=0 , format = format, please tell me how to fix this error. I have attached a screenshot of the error

My code

```
 privat[![enter image description here][1]][1]e void playVideo() {
        String path = mVideoFile.get(position).getPath();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "App")
        );
        concatenatingMediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource();
        for (int i = 0; i<mVideoFile.size(); i++){
            new File(String.valueOf(mVideoFile.get(i)));
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(uri)));
            concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource);

            playerView.setPlayer(player);
            playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            player.prepare(concatenatingMediaSource);
          //  player.seekTo(position, C.TIME_UNSET);

            playError();

        }
    }

    private void playError() {
        player.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

                Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
```

Comment: The error which I am getting is that -- mediacodec video renderer error index=0 , format = format

Comment: Can you share an example of a video which does not play?

Comment: hi, here is video which has over 1980*1080 file resulation,

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CueEqSc0txB_JwDBZ5pMoRCU_TUNoHBG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The video you shared in the comments is encoded with H264 codec using high profile - see the output below from ffprobe:

```js
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'production ID_4297545.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2020-05-02T14:48:25.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:12.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15077 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 3840x2160, 15074 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-05-02T14:48:25.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
```

Android devices by default support Baseline profile - you can see the supported media information here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#video-formats

You may find that some devices do actually support high profile encodings, but it is not guaranteed so it is usually better to re encode your video to baseline profile to ensure the widest device coverage possible.

Comment: So, there are some app like Mx player which play high resolution video well even at any device. So do you have any idea how I can add that type feature in app? please tell me

Comment: If the device does not support High profile natively, as Android does not require devices to, you may still be able to playback if you have a SW decoder library you can use - see this answer and the git link they highlight: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/683 This will not be insignificant work and the SW solution will likely use more power and battery. If you can rencode to baseline you might find it easier in the long run at this time.

Comment: Hi, Can you edit my code? Because I have spent many hours but I did not get a result. So I am requesting you, Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much your help... I have done my code and It is working fine

Comment: @Adobetutorial Can you please post your solution here so it will help to everyone. I am facing the same issue in playing 1080 resolution video and not able to find any solution. Thank you.